# saving seat arrangement in Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi can some one suggest me a way to save seat arrangement which is nXm matrix in a mysql table. Following are how we generate the nXm table

- Admin specifies the no of rows and column of a bus
- Admin selects whether a particular element of matrix is a

  1. Seat
  2. Passage
  3. Sleeper

  Note: A sleeper  occupies 2 elements
- This matrix has to be saved in the database

I want each element of the matrix to have a unique id with one exception in case of a sleeper two elements are same

Comment: Where is your table schema ? **OR** this is another show me how to do this and that?

Answer (score 2):

MatrixTable

```
|MatrixID|Rows|Colls|
```

where MatrixID is the primary key

SeatTakenTable

```
|MatrixID|Row|Column|PassangerType|ElementID|
```

Where all Columns are the composit primary key

There is no nead to save free seats because there wont be any collusions when you use this "logical" key

For a sleeper you will hae to insert two rows in the SetTaken table with the same ElemntID

Comment: @Web Developer edited. I´´ sure ther was an sollution that did not need another column but I simply orgot to write it in my answer and now I can not renember it -.-