# Drag and drop seating arrangement in Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

We are creating a website on buses  and booking tickets for the same. Here the admin expects to create and modify the seating arrangement using  drag and drop (including the driver's seat) according to his wish.

This seating arrangement is to be maintained / recorded in a database table (in mysql). The table structure talked about in [saving seat arrangement in Mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551651/saving-seat-arrangement-in-mysql-table) seems to be pretty close to the one we are looking for

The non-feasible part for us is the drag and drop and its maintainance in a mysql database table which is expected to be responsive to every drag and drop and should update itself accordingly.

I am sure somebody is going to come to out with a solution.I guess ajax could be used but we are pretty much new to ajax. Therefore I would really request an elaborate reply if someone comes out with a solution in ajax.

(**N. B.**: Coding is to be done in php)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement could not only be fulfilled by only PHP, you **need to use javascript/jquery and html5** as well..

Here is a **good example** of `drag and drop jquery` and `retrieving the array`.. A demo and download is available there for the example..

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/

and also have a look at this..

http://devheart.org/examples/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/2-saving-and-loading-items/index.html

Comment: I really appreciate the help... I went through the links that you provided and they did give us a start. The solution that you provided sorts or rearranges a given set of seats. We also wanted to include 'remove a seat' feature which could help the admin to remove a seat(s) from a bus. Can this feature be added along with the sorting?

Comment: yes.. you can use `jquery's hide()` property...
https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide..
and get a `flag` saved for every `seat` like `0 for removed seat and 1 for present seat`.. somewhere in an `array` or `html hidden fields`...

Comment: Is it feasible / advisable to keep track of the mouse co-ordinates in a database for the above-mentioned feature?

Comment: yes.. you must keep track of your data somewhere.. Otherwise how would you be able to save it to your database??

Comment: and also check below links.. it will help you out..
1) http://www.blaineehrhart.com/blog/ajax-drag-and-drop-list-ordering..
2) http://www.blaineehrhart.com/demo/dnd-dojo-demo.php..
3) http://tool-man.org/ToolManDHTML/sorting.html..
4) http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager..
5) http://ext4sap.free.fr/sortable0.4.html