# Drag and drop save page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to save the position of list items after drag and drop. So that when next time I will open the same page then I will get the previously changed position of list items.

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: Are you using [sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable) ?

Comment: 1- Check for Ajax Request. 2- Add a column in your database to manage the order.

Comment: yes. I am using sortable

Answer (score 1):

Create a Table in your database for that, and save the position of the items in there. Like this you can access the position-data easily.

Answer (score 0):

The following link could prove to be useful to you. It involves drag and drop seating arrangement but at least you could get a start after going through the link.

[Drag and drop seating arrangement in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086497/drag-and-drop-seating-arrangement-in-php)